# Abrir App ao inicializar android

Tags: android, intel-xdk

Fiz um App Android no IntelXDK, está funcionando normal, agora quero que ele abra automaticamente quando eu ligar o celular.

Sei que existe na playstore alguns aplicativos que fazem isso, mas a principio eu não queria usar nenhum app de terceiros e sim fazer o meu app inicializar sozinho.

Comment: nunca fiz uma implementação dessas no InteXDK, mas caso você desenvolva com o Android Studio, você precisará implementar uma funcionalidade nativa do Android, quer dizer chamar um serviço nativo do sistema Android para poder chamar seu app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se fosse no Android Studio era só você indicar na **tag** de permission do AndroidManifest.xml o código: `android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED`. Essa ação é uma exigência do Android para que o usuário da aplicação saiba que recursos a aplicação que ele esta instalando fará uso. Sem essa tag uma **RuntimeException** será disparada no momento em que a sua aplicação tentar usar o recurso.

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>`

Depois você deve criar um **BroadcastReceiver** que representará a ação que será executada no momento em que o dispositivo acabar de ligar totalmente. A classe BroadcastReceiver da API do Android tem o objetivo de executar um pequeno processamento em background. Geralmente é utilizada para interceptar Intents como a que é disparada no momento em que a o dispositivo se inicia.

```js
public class BootUpReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
   
     @Override
     public void onReceive(Context context, Intent i) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, MinhaActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(intent);
     }
 
}
```

No código acima dá para ver que quando o BroadcastReceiver for executado uma Activity será chamada, mas isso foi só o exemplo que achei. Você é livre para executar o que quiser nesse ponto como, iniciar um Service, uma tarefa agendada, etc...

Outro detalhe importante é que foi adicionado a flag `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` para exibir a Activity, pois até esse momento nenhuma Acitivity da aplicação foi iniciada, essa será a primeira. Caso essa flag não esteja presente uma exceção em tempo de execução será lançada.

Após criar o BroadcastReceiver você deve anunciá-lo no `AndroidManifest.xml` da aplicação assim como foi feito com as Activitys. Um detalhe a ser explicado é que a **IntentFilter** dentro da tag do Receiver indica que esse BroadacastReceiver irá ser executado quando a intent BOOT_COMPLETED acontecer. Traduzindo em miúdos... => **quando o dispositivo for ligado**.

```js
<receiver android:enabled="true"
  android:name=".receivers.BootUpReceiver"
  android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">
    <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Pronto, sua aplicação será iniciada automaticamente quando o dispositivo for ligado.

No Intel XDK o processo é igual, a única diferença é que em vez de implementar os passos no **AndroidManifest.xml**, você deve implementar no **intelxdk.config.additions**.

References

- https://androiddevbr.wordpress.com/2012/08/10/auto-start-faca-seu-aplicativo-ser-executado-quando-o-dispositivo-acabar-de-ligar-2/
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056570/how-to-autostart-an-android-application